# Get url parameters after # in java

Tags: java, facebook, jsf

I am trying to get the access_token from facebook. First I redirect to facebook using an url as the following

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&#38;client_id=7316713919&#38;redirect_uri=http://whomakescoffee.com:8080/app/welcome.jsf&#38;scope=publish_stream
```

Then I have a listener that gets the url.

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request =
                (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
                if (url.contains("access_token")) {
                    int indexOfEqualsSign = url.indexOf("=");
                    int indexOfAndSign = url.indexOf("&");
                    accessToken = url.substring(indexOfEqualsSign + 1, indexOfAndSign);
                    handleFacebookLogin(accessToken, fc);
                }
```

But it never gets inside the if..

How do I retrieve the parameter when it comes after a # instead of a usual parameter after ?.

The url looks something like

```
http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/#access_token=
    116122545078207|
    2.1vGZASUSFMHeMVgQ_9P60Q__.3600.1272535200-500880518|
    QXlU1XfJR1mMagHLPtaMjJzFZp4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL is incorrectly encoded. It's [XML-escaped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) instead of [URL-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). The `#` is a reserved character in URL's which represents the client-side fragment which is never sent back to the server side.

The URL should more look like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&client_id=7316713919&redirect_uri=http%3a%2f%2fwhomakescoffee.com%3a8080%2fapp%2fwelcome.jsf%26scope%3dpublish_stream

You can use [`java.net.URLEncoder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) for this.

Comment: But I am redirected to my page again and then the url in the adrressbar looks like http://whomakescoffee.com/app/welcome.jsf#access_token=
    116122545078207|
    2.1vGZASUSFMHeMVgQ_9P60Q__.3600.1272535200-500880518|
    QXlU1XfJR1mMagHLPtaMjJzFZp4

Comment: Are you saying that I can't get the access_token from the server side?

Comment: did you find a way to properly fetch the access token yet ?